# How to fix automatic breaks in text

Tags: html, css

Im creating a contact list with people's title, name, and email linked next to it but when I load up the preview, there is an extra break where I never added one.

I've tried moving my 
 tags, and changing the placements of the links.

```css
.contacts-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.contacts-text {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.subhead {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="contacts-header">Association Board 2019</h1>
<div class="contacts-text">
  <p class="subhead"><b>Association Officers</b></p>
  <br>
  <p><em>President:</em> Kim W</p><a href="mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
  <br>
  <p><em>Treasurer:</em> Fritz A</p><a href="mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
```

When I pull up the webpage, there is a break after the person's name and on the next line, the link appears. Please Help! (Sorry if it answer is simple, I'm just starting to code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To directly answer your question:

That is because you used `<p>` to contain the names.

`<p>` is called a [paragraph element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p). Without making it too techincal, one of a default style of paragraph element is:

```
display: block;
```

Elements with `display: block` will automatically [arranged vertically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout), thus a line break.

To change that behaviour, simply overwrite the block display style with an inline display style such as:

```
display: inline;
```

Working example:

```css
.contacts-header{
  text-align: center;
}
.contacts-text{
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.subhead{
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* THIS LINE */
p:not(.subhead) {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="contacts-header">Association Board 2019</h1> 
<div class="contacts-text">
  <p class="subhead"><b>Association Officers</b></p>
  <br>
  <p><em>President:</em> Kim W</p>
  <a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
  <br>
  <p><em>Treasurer:</em> Fritz A</p>
  <a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
</div>
```

#### PS

Of course, the more appropriate way is to wrap your ending `</p>` tag at the end of your paragraph, which is after the `<a>` emails.

Instead of this:

```
<p><em>President:</em> Kim W</p><a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
```

Do this:

```
<p><em>President:</em> Kim W <a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraph ending tag is breaking the line.  Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="contacts-header">Association Board 2019</h1> 
    <div class="contacts-text">
        <p class="subhead"><b>Association Officers</b></p>
    <br><p><em>President:</em> Kim W<a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com"> (********@gmail.com)</a></p>
    <br><p><em>Treasurer:</em> Fritz A<a href = "mailto: ********@gmail.com"> (********@gmail.com)</a></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here the main issue is your `<p></p>` tag so after removing your
>   `<p></p>` tag and some little changes in HTML works fine

.

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="contacts-header">Association Board 2019</h1>
<div class="contacts-text">
<p class="subhead"><b>Association Officers</b></p>
 <br>
  <div>
     <em>President:</em> Kim W
     <a href="mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
  </div>
  <div>
     <em>Treasurer:</em>Fritz A
     <a href="mailto: ********@gmail.com">(********@gmail.com)</a>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contacts-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.contacts-text {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.subhead {
  font-size: 18px; 
}
```

Here is the working example of that you can go thru

https://jsfiddle.net/0wh4njtf/4/